# How can I remove the prev and next button in datatable bootstrap pagination if there's only one or two pages?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a datatable and I enabled the pagination of my datatable. I want to remove the next and prev button when there are only one or two pages. How am I going to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This discussion may be helpful to you: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/511.

It links to a [DataTables example](http://live.datatables.net/xanoleyu/1/edit) illustrating how to hide the entire pagination section when no pagination is necessary.

If you further modify the JavaScript as follows, I think it would achieve your goal of only hiding 'Next' and 'Previous' when there are 1 or 2 pages. I tested this by setting the 'Show X Entries' in the top left of the table to 50, and it worked.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  table.on( 'draw', function () {
    $(table.table().container())
      .find('a.previous, a.next')
      .css( 'display', table.page.info().pages <= 2 ?
           'none' :
           'block'
      ) 
  } );
} );
```